# With jQuery-Mobile, how to insert icon into table cell

Tags: jquery-mobile, hover, icons

In the example 
  http://jsfiddle.net/yotam/n2mfy3hg/
there is a table with an anchor alert-button inside a table-cell.

```
<span>
  <a id="aimg" href="#" data-inline="true"
    class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-icon-search ui-btn-icon-notext"></a>
</span>
```

How can one have this 'alert' icon simply inserted in a table-cell,
without neither an anchor nor a button, thus
avoiding the unnecessary <a>-markup and undesired hover effect?

Comment: Could you please clarify your question? which _unnecessary markup_ are you talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple span with a couple of CSS rules to position it correctly for a jQM icon

```
<span class="ui-icon-alert ui-btn-icon-notext inlineIcon"></span>

.inlineIcon {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: 6px;
}
```

If you prefer the icon to be dark without the gray circle behind it:

```
<span class="ui-alt-icon ui-icon-alert ui-btn-icon-notext inlineIconNoDisk"></span>

.inlineIconNoDisk {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: 6px;
}
.inlineIconNoDisk:after {
    background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

> Here is your updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/n2mfy3hg/1/)** (both options are shown)